# NSIS Display license with a monospace font

Tags: nsis

Is there a way to display the license of the license page in a NSIS installer with a monospace font?

BTW, I'm doing the traditional:

```
; Welcome page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
; License page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "..\..\..\LICENSE.txt"
; Directory page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
```

But the license look pretty weird with the default sans-serif font used by the installer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outfile test.exe

!include WinMessages.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW licpageshow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function licpageshow
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
CreateFont $1 "Courier New" "$(^FontSize)"
GetDlgItem $0 $0 1000
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETFONT} $1 1
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```